# Pandas Series - How to use functions in a nested way?

Tags: python, pandas

When I tried to use simple multiplication on pandas Series, I get index to index result like this:

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) * pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
>>> 0    4
    1    10
    2    18
```

I want to do this operation in a "nested" way like this:

```
>>> 0    4
    1    5
    2    6
    3    8
    4    10
    5    12
    6    12
    7    15
    8    18
```

Is there a way to do this with a numpy or pandas way? Or do I need to use for loops? If I use for loops in big datasets, the process takes a really long time.

Also, how can I use this method with different functions as well? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
b = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])

c = pd.Series(np.multiply.outer(a, b).ravel())
```

Or use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
c = pd.Series(a.repeat(len(b)).values * np.tile(b, len(a)))
print (c)
0     4
1     5
2     6
3     8
4    10
5    12
6    12
7    15
8    18
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

Thank you `shivsn` for suggestion use [`numpy.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
c = pd.Series(np.outer(a, b).ravel())
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(2018)

N = 10000
a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000, size=N))
b = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000, size=N))

In [81]: %timeit pd.Series(np.outer(a, b).ravel())
1 loop, best of 3: 174 ms per loop

In [82]: %timeit pd.Series(np.multiply.outer(a, b).ravel())
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop

In [83]: %timeit pd.Series(a.repeat(len(b)).values * np.tile(b, len(a)))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.2 s per loop

In [84]: %%timeit
    ...: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a , b], names = ["a", "b"])
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
    ...: df['a'] * df['b']
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.01 s per loop
```

Comment: i don't think you need `np.multiply` it can just be `np.outer`.

Comment: @shivsn - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` method.

```
In[1]:
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a , b], names = ["a", "b"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
dataf = pd.DataFrame({"Result" : df['a'] * df['b']})
```

Output

```
Out[1]:
      Result
0       4
1       5
2       6
3       8
4      10
5      12
6      12
7      15
8      18
```

Answer (score 1):

One efficient way is to use `numpy`:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
b = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])

c = pd.Series((b.values * a.values[:, None]).ravel())
```

Result:

```
0     4
1     5
2     6
3     8
4    10
5    12
6    12
7    15
8    18
dtype: int64
```